# Nodejs streams Write, Read, Write

Tags: node.js, express, request

Basically what I'm trying to do is Write to my file from an external source, Read from that file and then re-Write to it with some updated style. I'm doing this to an image. Ex code:

```
var rawImg = urlHtml('img').attr('src'); // got the image from a website! 

var wStream = request(rawImg).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test.jpg')); //write img to file

var rStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'}); // read img from file
var wStream2 = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test-result.jpg') // output
```

The image does save to file, but anytime I try to read it I always get the error: { [Error: spawn ENOENT] code: 'ENOENT', errno: 'ENOENT', syscall: 'spawn' } - which means its not even there yet

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the file before it has been created. Try waiting for the file to be closed first:

```
var wStream = request(rawImg).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test.jpg'));

wStream.on('close', function() {
  var rStream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test.jpg', {encoding: 'base64'});
  var wStream2 = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test-result.jpg');
});
```

Comment: For some reason when I try to access the file it doesn't work I have no idea why

Comment: I've updated my answer, the `close` event might be better since that's when the backing file descriptor is closed.

Comment: It still doesnt work! I think I'll have to use a library maybe then it'll work, or should I use a transform stream?

Comment: I just tried the .on('end) function and I get nothing from the console!

Comment: Hint: What happens if you do `grep $something somefile > somefile` in the terminal?

Comment: I kind of figured out what i have to do but I'm not sure how to go about it. I need to use a transform stream using the request module.

I'm guessing as I did above with the first line:

    var wStream = request(rawImg).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/public/img/test.jpg'));

Then I have to turn it into a transform stream so it's both READABLE and WRITABLE.